# How to make curl request by passing raw data to post method?

Tags: php, curl, postman, symfony4

I have an API. In this API, I pass `X-AUTH_TOKEN` & `X-AUTH-KEY` as headers and in the body, I pass raw array data ["1", "2", "3"....]

I have tested it using postman, it is returning me response.

But when I implement it using symfony, I am getting `HTTP/2 404 returned for "`

This is what I have implemented in Symfony.

```
$response = $this->httpClient->request('POST', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'x-auth-token' => $authToken,
                'x-auth-key'   => $authKey
            ],
            'body' => [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
            ]
        ]);
```

Can anybody please help me how can I implement?

Thank You.

Comment: Http status 404 means that you're not calling the correct address, it's not an issue with the request body.
Can you double check, that your calling the correct address?

Comment: Yes I am calling the correct address. When I make get request without passing any body, it is returning me result.

Comment: I solved it. I have to pass `json` instead of `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `body` pass `json`

```
$response = $this->httpClient->request('POST', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'x-auth-token' => $authToken,
                'x-auth-key'   => $authKey
            ],
            'body' => [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
            ]
        ]);
```